# Using big-O notation to count the number of bits in x^2?

Tags: math, integer, big-o, bit

If x is an n-bit integer. What is the size (in bits) of x<sup>2</sup>?

I think the answer is O(n); is that correct? The way I thought about it is adding a number to itself that number amount of times means that there will be n operations, therefore O(n). Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose x has n bits. This means x = Θ(2<sup>n</sup>). Therefore, x<sup>2</sup> = Θ(2<sup>n</sup> · 2<sup>n</sup>) = Θ(2<sup>2n</sup>), so the number now has about twice as many bits as before. This means that if there were n bits to begin with, there are now about 2n = Θ(n) bits.

While the answer you gave of O(n) is correct, your reasoning is invalid. Note that the question isn't asking for how long it takes to compute x<sup>2</sup>, but rather the number of bits it contains. The time to compute x<sup>2</sup> is a different question.

Hope this helps!